# Why do I get this two whole different mesh looks depending on method of display?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm trying to isolate certain parts of my sculpture but somewhere in the process I realized that the looks of the basic tile frame I was using changed between the wireframe in Object mode and Edit mode.

It's as if they had whole different vertices...
[image: EDIT MODE]
[image: Object mode]

Comment: Whatever those are, which the images do a poor job of illustrating, they seem to have pretty bad topology and suffer from geometry issues

Comment: I still dont master topology. Im talking about the surrounding frame on the right. The floor in an shape of a cross.